# How to avoid pushing the commits when pushing git tags?

Tags: git

When tagging in git, I can

push all new tags:

```
git push --tags
```

or push specific tags:

```
git push origin v1.5
```

But in both cases any new pending commits will get pushed out as well. How to aviod pushing the commits?

Comment: A tag points to a commit. It's useless unless the commits are also available. The fact you don't want commits to be pushed may point to an error in your thinking about the usage of Git.

Comment: I'm tagging older commits. Commits already exist on the remote. I just don't want to push any new commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither form pushes new commits to the remote, unless the tags you push refer to commits that don't already exist in the remote.

Answer (score 1):

As a tag in git is "nothing" else than an alias to a commit - you can't. It would incoherently change the git-base and new clones would see the tag but would not be able to checkout it out.

If you really want to corrupt your git remote repository and if you have filesystem access on the server hosting your git repository you could create a file in `[.git]/refs/tags/`. The filename will be the tag-name and the content will be the sha1 which refers to the commit.

Trying to list the tags with `git tag -l` results in `error: refs/tags/<tagname> does not point to a valid object!` .